# How to copy objects in different region s3 buckets from aws china to aws global by using lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Basically, I can achieve this goal by using aws cli to copy object from aws china to my local server and then copy to aws global.

However, I have to use lambda to achieve this goal and I didn't got a hint when seeing aws official guide. What's worse, I know there are some policies preventing transport data from China to outside, which make this goal more difficult to achieve...

Is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey and welcome to stackoverflow, so could we see some code and then an example of errors you're facing?

Comment: I found putObject can put object between s3 in China and s3 in global.